# How to xml element and xml element name?

Tags: c#, xml

This is my xml

```
<configuration>
      <login>Your login id</login> 
      <password>Your password</password>
      <option1>option1 value</option1>
      <optiony>optionY value</optiony>
</configuration>
```

How do I loop to get xml element name and element value?

```
login, Your login id
password, Your password 
Etc....
```

The xml element name and value is unknown it can be any value.

Comment: Well where are you getting the XML from? Have you loaded it into an `XElement` or something similar? Have you tried *anything* yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("yourfile.xml");
XmlElement eb = (XmlElement) doc.GetElementsByTagName("configuration")[0];
XmlNodeList elemList = eb.GetElementsByTagName("*");
string output="";
foreach (XmlElement el in elemList)
{
    output += el.Name+", ";
    output += el.InnerText+"\r\n";
}
```